# Selecting the index column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'customer' :  ['customer2', 'customer1'], 'item1': [12, 13], 'item2' : [3, 28],'item3': [2, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'customer' :  ['customer1', 'customer2'], 'item?': ['item1', 'item1'], 'quantity' : [2, 5]})

df = df.set_index('customer').add(pd.pivot_table(df2,index='customer',columns='item?',values='quantity')).fillna(df.set_index('customer')).astype(int)

print(df['customer'])
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Inzamelhelden\twilio.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(df['customer'])
  File "C:\Users\Inzamelhelden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3805, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Inzamelhelden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3802, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'customer'
```

The expected result would be the 'name' column of dataframe one.

Comment: ```customer``` is your ```index``` in the DF, not a column.

Comment: which you specified yourself in ```pivot_table```

Answer (score 0):

**The customer column in the index so you need to use the below code for getting the value of**

```
df.reset_index()['customer']
```